# Boot windows 10 with USB but have Ubuntu on hard drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, usb

I have a hardrive with Ubuntu on it but Ubuntu is having some serious errors so I decide to change to windows 10 I bought windows 10 from Microsoft and put it on a usb. Plugged in the USB. I went to BIOS and changed the boot order to SanDisk drive (my USB) as priority yet it still goes straight to Ubuntu. How can I get windows 10 now?

Comment: It's easier to fix Ubuntu (or any Linux distribution) than Windows. Please explain the actual problem.

Comment: Brand of PC please?

Comment: @biswapriyo I am not interested in fixing ubuntu and I just want windows.

Comment: @moab it's custom built

Comment: Motherboard brand?

Comment: Don't worry I just forgot to make a bootable USB drive. Simple mistake see verified answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply copy Windows 10 to an USB and boot it up as normal. It doesn’t work that way.

Instead, you have to make a bootable USB drive with several software, such as Windows Media Creation tool or Rufus. Without a bootable USB drive, your computer will skip your USB and start to boot from your hard drive as it’s the second one.

[[Source 1]](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6734-windows-10-installation-tool.html) [[Source 2]](https://rufus.ie/)